# How to make \textregistered or \texttrademark bold in subsection title?

Tags: symbols, bold, section-titles

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=3em]{tocline}{figure}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{hyperref}               
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{ae} 

\begin{document}
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
 \tableofcontents
    \subsubsection{Ecoflex\texorpdfstring{\texttrademark}{t} 00-30}
\end{document}
```

When I define a new subsubsection with a trademark or textregistered symbol, the output of this symbol is not bold. Using  `\usepackage[outline]{contour}` makes the symbols bold in the text but not in the subsection title. Is there any way to bold these symbols in the title?

`\subsubsection{Ecoflex\texorpdfstring{\texttrademark}{t} 00-30}`
leads to

[image: Symbols not bold in section title]

Edit: deleting the `ae` package and replacing it with `lmodern` resolved my problem.

Comment: I get a bold trademark in a minimal example (without needing contour). So show a complete example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what do you mean by complete example?

Comment: Usually, the idea when giving examples on this site is to make them minimal, yet _compilable_ so that others can reproduce your problem easily. More details are given in the answers on [this meta question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{ae}`. It's obsolete and deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `ae` is obsolete and has been deprecated for about twenty years.

Remove `\usepackage{ae}` and you'll get the expected output.

You can see the problem in the log file where you find

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TS1/aess/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TS1/cmr/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `texttrademark' on input line 13.
```

No such warning occurs without the deprecated package.